# Deactivating a button in corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How to deactivate a button in corona?
I want a button(any image with event listener acting as a button)which can be disabled.I want to enable it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply remove the listener from the image:

```
button:removeEventListener("tap", myListener)
```

and then add it back when you want it to be active again.

```
button:addEventListener("tap", myListener)
```

Comment: [`button:setEnabled()`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/ButtonWidget/setEnabled.html) is another option

Comment: Wouldn't that require him to be using a button widget?

Comment: yes, it does requires it to be a button, possibly using an image for its default appearance.

Comment: I am not using a button.I am using an image as a button.And i have that event listener in composer function create scene.Now can i remove that listener from outside the composer functions?Thank u.

Comment: Yes, you can remove it outside.